# Monitor when an excelfile is opened using VBA

Tags: vba, file, events

I want to monitor when an excel file is opened and extract the filename using VBA.
I want to code to be placed in another excel file and not to file there is opened.

I could use a loop running every 1 sec where I count the numbers of workbooks -
“workbooks.Count” - but I'm wondering if there is another way, maybe using events

Answer (score 3):

Instead of running an every-one-second timer, you can use the event `Application.OnWindow`.

This event is activated when a new workbook is opened, BUT also whenever the focus changes from one workbook to another. Therefore, in order to track the names of all the workbooks that were opened during the session, you need to put them in a `Collection`, so that each name is added once and only once.

Add the following code to a code module:

```
Public openedFiles As New Collection

Sub StartTracking() '<~~ run this macro to start tracking any opened workbook
    Application.OnWindow = "OnWnd"
End Sub
Sub StopTracking() '<~~ run this macro to stop the tracking
    Application.OnWindow = ""
End Sub

Sub OnWnd()
    If ActiveWorkbook Is ThisWorkbook Then Exit Sub
    For Each x In openedFiles
        If x = ActiveWorkbook.fullName Then Exit Sub
    Next

    openedFiles.Add ActiveWorkbook.fullName

    ' An example usage: display the names of the files opened during session
    Dim s As String: s = "workbooks opened so far: " & vbCrLf
    For Each F In openedFiles
        s = s & vbCrLf & F
    Next
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

Comment: I've never seen the OnWindow event before. Interesting, no Application event required. I see this was added with Excel 2013.

Comment: @DougGlancy Thanks for the remark. Besides, I have Excel 2010 and it has it.  I dont know since when exactly it exists...

Comment: Good solution 
But I have an extra question then.  If a file is closed and then opened later on, then it will not be monitored, as I understand your code.

Comment: Actually it would be nice, if I was able to be able to run some code, just before a file is closed.

Comment: If a file is closed and then opened later on, it is logged only once in this code, but it can easily be modified so that it can be logged twice. But concerning the last requirement, monitoring the closing of a file, *before it is closed*, unfortunately I dont know of a way to do this without putting in the file itself  a `Workbook_BeforeClose` routine.

Comment: Ultimately, there is a way to add the routine on the spot in the newly opened workbook, programmatically, but that's a rarely used feature.

Comment: I see and understand what you mean. 
I'll try to modify the code